# FileUtils.iterateFiles IGNORECASE

Tags: java, file, file-io, apache-commons-io

I need to find files in directories and subdirectories by type of extension and ignorecase mode, this is my code:

```
String[] patron = {"doc", "xls", "ppt"};
Iterator iter =  FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File(directories), patron, true);
```

I also need to return the files with extension like Doc, Doc, ...  ignorecase

Answer (score 4):

Use the other version of the method and pass your own filter:

```
String[] extensions = new String[] {"doc", "xls", "ppt"};
IOFileFilter filter = new SuffixFileFilter(extensions, IOCase.INSENSITIVE);
Iterator iter = FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File(directorio), filter, DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);
```

Notice the use of `IOCase.INSENSITIVE`.

Comment: Thank you very much, also add the line to the recursive search:
IOFileFilter filter = new SuffixFileFilter(patron, IOCase.INSENSITIVE);
Iterator iter =  FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File(directorio), filter, DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);

Comment: My mistake, the last parameter must be a directory filter. I updated the code, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must refer the documentation of FileUtils at 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

The definition you are using

```
public static Iterator iterateFiles(File directory,
                                    String[] extensions,
                                    boolean recursive)
```

Allows iteration over the files in a given directory (and optionally its subdirectories) which match an array of extensions. This method is based on listFiles(File, String[], boolean).

**extensions** - an array of extensions, ex. {"java","xml"}. If this parameter is null, all files are returned.recursive - if true all subdirectories are searched as well

*`it should return files irrespective of doc or DOc or dOC they are all same.`*

Else there is one more definition given where you can apply filters.

You can use this definition for iterateFiles

```
iterateFiles(File directory, IOFileFilter fileFilter, IOFileFilter dirFilter)
```

In this you have to pass an IOFileFilter object, you can implement the given accept method definition

```
boolean accept(File dir, String name)
```

The documentation of IOFileFilter can be found at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

I actually wanted to comment on @AurA's answer but I am not allowed to because it says "You must have 50 reputation to comment".

```
listFiles(File, String[], boolean)
```

is case-sensitive, so it does NOT "return files irrespective of doc or DOc or dOC".